# Which Arduino Uno pin corresponds to TCNT0?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, atmega

I am trying to count using the internal ATMega328 to create a Theremin based on [this](http://interface.khm.de/index.php/lab/interfaces-advanced/theremin-as-a-capacitive-sensing-device/) concept.
I am using the internal timer1 and timer0 counters. However, I am unable to find documentation for which pin to use as an input to trigger the corresponding counter increase.

Pin 5 corresponds to TCNT1, which pin corresponds to TCNT0?

Comment: Did you even bother to do a search?  https://www.google.com/search?q=atmega328+pinout&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwijp4O55MzUAhVE8GMKHfTZA9UQ_AUIBigB&biw=1920&bih=988

Comment: The registers for the timers actually seem to have pins corresponding to the Arduino pins. I did find those, but they seem to be different from what I found (do not work as described). Also, I use DuckDuckGo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCNT1 and TCNT0 are both timer registers in the microcontroller.  Neither is associated with any pin at all unless you write timer-based code or timer interrupts that interact with input or output pins.  You need to study the Atmel datasheet for the ATmega328.  All registers and use of the timers are covered in detail.  The design you refer to doesn't appear to use Timer0 at all.

Example:

"Registers
The Timer/Counter 0 register (TCNT0) and Output Compare TC0x registers (OCR0x) are 8-bit registers.
Interrupt request (abbreviated to Int.Req. in the block diagram) signals are all visible in the Timer Interrupt
Flag Register 0 (TIFR0). All interrupts are individually masked with the Timer Interrupt Mask Register 0
(TIMSK0). TIFR0 and TIMSK0 are not shown in the figure."

"The Timer/Counter (TCNT1), Output Compare Registers (OCRA/B), and Input Capture Register (ICR1)
are all 16-bit registers. Special procedures must be followed when accessing the 16-bit registers. These
procedures are described in section Accessing 16-bit Registers."

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am using a second counter because I use two sensors, but I think I don't quite understand the whole structure of this. I might use a camera for what tracking instead...

Comment: @NikiNeu If you found this helpful, an upvote and/or "Accept" will help others find it as well.